# Dynamically casting objects from FieldInfo.GetValue in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to iterate through all the fields in an instance of a class and extract their name / data. The fields themselves are instances of custom classes for storing data with some specific features I needed. The following works:

```
        foreach (var v in typeof(CentralParams).GetFields())
        {

            if(v.GetValue(_centralParams).GetType() == typeof(BoolEventProperty))
            {
                BoolEventProperty prop = (BoolEventProperty) v.GetValue(_centralParams);
                print(v.Name + "   " + prop.Value);
            }
            
            if(v.GetValue(_centralParams).GetType() == typeof(FloatEventProperty))
            {
                FloatEventProperty prop = (FloatEventProperty) v.GetValue(_centralParams);
                print(v.Name + "   " + prop.Value);
            }
            
            if(v.GetValue(_centralParams).GetType() == typeof(IntEventProperty))
            {
               IntEventProperty prop = (IntEventProperty) v.GetValue(_centralParams);
               print(v.Name + "   " + prop.Value);
            }

        }
```

However I have to manually check for the type of the object in the field, then cast it to a new instance of that type in order to access the Value member. This is annoying as every time I add a new data type to the CentralParams class I will have to handle it explicitly here.

Is there a way I can dynamically cast it to an empty variable of the correct type?

`v.GetValue(_centralParams).GetType()` returns the type I need so seems like it should be possible.

Something along the lines of

```
            var type = v.GetValue(_centralParams).GetType();

            var prop = (type)v.GetValue(_centralParams);
```

Thanks

Comment: [FieldInfo.FieldType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection.FieldInfo.FieldType);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C# 8.0 you can use [pattern-matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0). Something like this:

```cs
foreach (var v in typeof(CentralParams).GetFields())
{
    var property = v.GetValue(_centralParams);
    var value = property switch
    {
        BoolEventProperty prop => $"{prop.Value} from bool",
        FloatEventProperty prop => $"{prop.Value} from float",
        IntEventProperty prop => $"{prop.Value} from int",
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown type {property?.GetType()}")
    };

    print(v.Name + "   " + value);
}
```